# Hacking resources

Tags: security

I'm currently developing a web application which has a lot of javascript working behind it.  Before I deploy it (which will take a couple of months), I want to make sure that it is atleast a bit secure in terms of attacks.

I saw [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15966/is-it-necessary-for-a-web-developer-to-know-how-to-hack-website) link already but it doesn't have any resources that I could use to learn the 'art' of hacking. I don't want to exploit other sites, I just want to learn it to make my site safe.

Comment: Hacking/Security -- IT Security is more appropriate site: http://security.stackexchange.com/ -- have a look there.

Comment: Thank You. That seems to have what I wanted! Sry, I can't upvote you yet..

Comment: If you want to secure your web app, then you need to learn about web security, which includes common attacks & vulnerabilities, but also covers the standard defenses against them and general best practices. Focusing on resources that only teach you how to hack websites is the wrong way to go about it, as it won't give you the whitehat knowledge developed for/by security professionals. E.g. you might learn about the common scripts used to exploit websites, but you won't learn about coding practices that lead to less security bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The standard authority in this area is probably [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page). See in particular the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project), which describes the most widespread and dangerous security mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this Linux distro. I stumbled upon it a few months ago. Definitely useful for what you are trying to accomplish. Hope this is helpful.

http://www.backtrack-linux.org/